# Why HashRouter in react-router v6 is not recommended?

Tags: react-router

On every `react-router` v6 documentation page which mentions `HashRouter` there is a short warning text stating that this kind of routing is not recommended. There is no explanation why.

Are there any **major** disadvantages? Does it break any api somehow?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974369/what-is-the-difference-between-hashrouter-and-browserrouter-in-react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer.... some devs think hash routing produces "ugly" URLs... but no, really, hash routing serves a purpose where perhaps the server environment isn't setup to handle current HTML or otherwise needs to handle all page requests at a static URL.

This is about as much explanation as the docs provide.

[HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router)

> `<HashRouter>` is for use in web browsers when the URL should not (or
> cannot) be sent to the server for some reason. This may happen in some
> shared hosting scenarios where you do not have full control over the
> server. In these situations, `<HashRouter>` makes it possible to store
> the current location in the hash portion of the current URL, so it is
> never sent to the server.

It's basically, "Only use hash routing if that's what you need and you know what you are doing." I think it's generally the case that if you don't really know what you are doing or need that you really just need the `BrowserRouter`.

> Are there any major disadvantages? Does it break any api somehow?

I wouldn't say there are ***major*** disadvantages to using the `HashRouter`, it just serves a different purpose, like the `NativeRouter` on native mobile devices, or the `MemoryRouter` in node environments. I don't know if you are asking if it breaks any *specific* APIs using the `HashRouter`, but I'm inclined to say no, it still works with redux, fetch/axios, etc... and just about anything else I can think of I've used along with hash routing.

Comment: How is it serving different purpose compared to `BrowserRouter`? Looks like it duplicates its functionality when it comes to routing in SPAs, as both of them can be used interchangeably.

Comment: @jligeza Are you asking about this from the React app's perspective? If so, then yeah, routing and navigation is routing and navigation, that's why it doesn't have any "major disadvantages" or break apis, etc. Where they differ is in their use cases, i.e. where one needs to be used instead of the other. For example, if you deploy your app to Github, they don't support HTML5 so you can't use a `BrowserRouter` there. In other words, which you need to use depends on external (*to the app*) constraints by the server environment where the app is deployed. Does this make sense?

Comment: Okay, so in the end it is "ugly" url and no extra server configuration required vs. 
"pretty" url with requirement of extra server configuration.

Comment: Hello recent voter, do you have some feedback for what could be improved in this answer to make it more helpful/useful?

Comment: Hash is merely a plain string which doesn't get parsed by any of the browser interfaces, outside of maybe `encodeURI()`/`decodeURI()`. You basically have to write your own parser if you want to derive any meaningful state from it (and you will if you went that route in the first place). And also make sure none of these "routes" collide with actual element IDs on the page, otherwise you'll have subtle but annoying to debug problems.

Comment: And it's simply non-semantic, since the dawn of times and to this year (2024) it means a pointer to a particular element within the document. So yes, there are major disadvantages to using it and it should only be used in legacy projects which can't update React nor the router lib for some reason or have to support ancient browsers without History API.

Comment: @BillerBuilder Thanks for the feedback. You are more than welcome to provide an answer of your own to make these points. I don't think I've run into issues like you describe though, do you have more tangible examples? I think also my statement "serves a purpose where perhaps the server environment isn't setup to handle current HTML or otherwise needs to handle all page requests at a static URL" covers the edge cases you specifically call out.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: If your site is static, use whatever, it does not matter. But if you have a backend, using hash routing is recommended aproach, and not just for react.

Explanation: When hash is used, only your frontend application gets the request, no calls are made to backend. This is important for production enviroments, where you have some backened and/or some reverse proxy(like NGINX etc.), API Gateway etc. Without hash, request will need to be handled by them first, and if no endpoint is found, request is sent to frontend. This creates unnecessary calls, which leads to performance issues, unhandled paths, etc.. And in modern cloud enviroments, this means more money.

Comment: Just to add. You can use without hash, and handle all as needed, you will not make a mistake. Somethimes is better, somethimes not. That needs to be evaluetad on project basis, setup and needs.

Comment: Afaik changing the route with `BrowserRouter` does not send any requests to the server.

Only problem is that with `BrowserRouter` you need to configure your back end to handle the url correctly when the page is loaded for the first time or reloaded -- the BE needs to return the React app even when there are extra path segments (from the client-side routing) after the path at which the app is hosted (aka the app root I guess?).

If your are hosting the site through GitHub pages for example, any client-side route path segments will lead to gh pages trying to look for a file at that path.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "static site"? I though of static websites as sites with "little javascript" so probably no React, let alone client side routing. Am I wrong on that?

Comment: Oh I see, you mean static as in they don't request any data from APIs/the BE?
I feel like that's not super clear because in my mind hosting a static website is still counts as part of the BE so there is a backend.